# Delete records from table A where col 1 and col2 are in table B

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am wanting to delete records from a table if multiple columns in this table are in another table.

Currently, I usually just concatenate the columns and use the WHERE IN method:

```
DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE Col1+Col2 IN (SELECT Col1+Col2 FROM TableB)
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi - please take the time to register your account.  That will give you notifications from the site when you get a new answer, etc.  It also makes it easier to log in from another computer, or your phone, etc.  Also, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, you'd want to join to the two tables together, and delete rows from TableA that match rows in TableB.  Something like this:

```
DELETE a
FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Col1 = b.Col1
        AND a.Col2 = b.Col2;
```

Using the method you show in your question might result in the wrong rows being deleted.  Here's an example to show what I mean:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TableA', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TableA;
END
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TableB', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TableB;
END

CREATE TABLE #TableA
(
    i varchar(5) NOT NULL
    , j varchar(5) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE #TableB
(
    i varchar(5) NOT NULL
    , j varchar(5) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TableA (i, j)
VALUES ('asdf', 'lk')
    , ('asd', 'flk');

INSERT INTO #TableB (i, j)
VALUES ('as', 'dflk')
    , ('asd', 'flk');
```

First, we'll see what values are in both tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM #TableA;

SELECT *
FROM #TableB;
```

```
╔══════╦═════╗
║  i   ║  j  ║
╠══════╬═════╣
║ asdf ║ lk  ║
║ asd  ║ flk ║
╚══════╩═════╝

╔═════╦══════╗
║  i  ║  j   ║
╠═════╬══════╣
║ as  ║ dflk ║
║ asd ║ flk  ║
╚═════╩══════╝
```

The intention would be to delete the bottom row, while retaining the top row, in TableA.  However, if we run this:

```
DELETE FROM #TableA
WHERE #TableA.i + #TableA.j IN (SELECT #TableB.i + #TableB.j FROM #TableB);

SELECT *
FROM #TableA;
```

We'll see both rows are gone from TableA.

This statement, however, results in only the correct row being removed from TableA:

```
DELETE a
FROM #TableA a
    INNER JOIN #TableB b ON a.i = b.i
        AND a.j = b.j;
SELECT *
FROM #TableA;
```

Results:

```
╔══════╦════╗
║  i   ║ j  ║
╠══════╬════╣
║ asdf ║ lk ║
╚══════╩════╝
```